# Single player Rocket League: does my team get dumber over a season?

Tags: rocket-league

I've played several seasons of Rocket League single player and I feel like I've noticed a trend: after a few winning games, my team seems to get much much dumber.  I'm not talking about failing to set up / take advantage of a near-goal rebound.  I'm talking about my bot friend suddenly deciding to sit quietly in goal, watching the ball slowly roll past.

I know that Psyonix has announced that bots adjust to [average player skill level](http://rocketleague.psyonix.com/patch-notes/).  Am I seeing an actual intended effect?  Or am I just exposing corner cases in the AI logic?

Follow-up some time later with some of the more obvious symptoms of your teammates throwing the game: these are All Star AIs but they will stop jumping early (anticipating the ball) and you will be the MVP for the game more often (they'll have significantly fewer shots on goal).

Comment: Anecdotally, I've seen the AI have very consistent behavior over a season (even if some of it was bad). I think what you are seeing are just situations where the AI will always perform bad, but either by luck or circumstance you saw those events occur more later in the season.  I've learned certain tricks like to not chase the friendly AI when they are facing your goal - because they tend to "accidentally" hit it in much more often. Silly computers...

Comment: @EBongo you are describing the behavior of the easy AI. I'm talking about All Star AI.

Comment: I am talking about the Rookie AI, yes.  I was pointing out that it behaved consistently though, and if Rookie behaves consistently there is some reason to expect All Star would too.  Given the difficulties in programming the AI for this game, I find it hard to imagine that the AI would dynamically adjust to "true skill".  I think what you referred to in the [patch notes](http://www.rocketleaguegame.com/news/2015/07/patch-notes-v1-03/) merely indicates that in a multiplayer game, the added AI will match the players average experience level.

Comment: So in other words, when a player leaves a 4v4 game with all All Stars, the bot that gets added would be an All Star, and not a Rookie.  That seems a pretty simple thing to do, compared to branching AI behavior based on running average player skill.

Answer (score 4):

There is no reason for bots to actually do that since they're specifically designed *to play along with you*. So a bot sitting in the goal box and not going after the nearby ball is definitely a hangup in the bot's path logic or something related to that.

It's very likely that Psyonix's AI update set some things back. This happens to pretty much everyone designing AI because there are so many factors that go into intelligent play.

Comment: Thanks but I'm aware that AI programming can be challenging. That doesn't really answer my question though: is there scaling going on in single player?  If so, what "skill level" is it measuring?

Comment: Perhaps there is a skill level compensation effect in single player. If you score every goal in every game, your team's AI will be lessened. There's really no way to tell for sure if this is true though.

Answer (score 0):

The AI has done that many times, including scoring own goals, this is probably due to the new update in the AI play, it doesn't happen all the time though.